# Bluetooth problem everytime I switch between ElementaryOS / Windows 10

Tags: bluetooth, microsoft-windows

Whenever I switch I get problems with bluetooth.

**It's not the problem with pairing**, I copied my bluetooth devices keys from Windows to Elementary so I resolved problem with pairing devices every OS change.

The problem is that sometimes when I switch from eOS to Windows I have no bluetooth icon in Windows action center and bluetooth simply not work. I used to solve it with random Windows Updating and resolving problem with built-in windows troubleshooting, but now I can't resolve it that way for some reason and... even If I could resolve it at this point I am sick of it.

Also, when I try to switch back to eOS afer that bug occurs in Windows 10 I can't use bluetooth either in Elemenary and the bluetooth indicator icon becomes hidden in the elementary upper panel (wingpannel).
It looks like that: [image]

**My laptop: Lenovo Y50-70**

Comment: There are problems with hardware when you restart from windows into elementary os, but if you shut down widnows and start into elementary os everything is fine. Try this if you didn't.